# VS code Error persists after editing the file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, webpack

I am new to Angulaar, now I have tried to implement bootstrap, I misspelled the path in styles.css file, so I got following error:

```
an unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
```

After that I corrected the path but error persists, I cleaned Editor history with Ctrl Shift P
but it does not work. Is there any way to do Clean/Rebuild in VS Code?

P S I removed entirely the import path to see the result but still get File not found Exception

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get this error? During angular build?

Comment: When I tried to execute command ng serve -o

Comment: Then, if you are sure that you've fixed the path, just restart this command?

Comment: I restart this command but still get the same error, from what I see in log file, it seems to be Webpack related issue

Comment: Then probably path is stil not fixed. Hard to say without any steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: I removed the entire path and checked the file is not referenced in entire solution...

Comment: I have found the solution: the generated path was copied in angular.json file, so I fixed it there

Comment: Provide some code to see what are you doing please